# Difference between some & (first (filter in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have seen suggested that `some` can be used instead of `(first (filter` but I'm confused by a discrepancy in how they work. Can any one please explain why this doesn't yield the same result?

```
(some (comp #{:fu} :id) [{:id :fu :baz :bar}])
> :fu

(first (filter (comp #{:fu} :id) [{:id :fu :baz :bar}]))
> {:id :fu, :baz :bar}
```

Is there any other, idiomatic and less verbose, way to do `(first (filter` i.e. get the first item satisfying a predicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two uses are not semantically equivalent; each has its own, distinct use case.

---

```
(some (comp #{:fu} :id) [{:id :fu :baz :bar}])
> :fu
```

This returns the item as it exists after being filtered, in accordance with [the documented behavior of `some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some).

---

```
(first (filter (comp #{:fu} :id) [{:id :fu :baz :bar}]))
> {:id :fu, :baz :bar}
```

This returns the item as it exists before being filtered, if and only if it passes the filter. This is true because [`filter` uses its function argument only to determine whether an item should be included in its output stream](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/filter); it does not mutate items in any way other than excluding the ones the filter function rejects.